# tidyverse divide by rowSums using pipe

Tags: r, tidyverse

I want to do `df/rowSums(df)` in tidyverse.

I tried `df %>% ./rowSums(.)` but this does not work.

Do you have ideas? Thanks so much!

Comment: Just place it inside `{}` `df %>% {./rowSums(.)}`

Answer (score 1):

We can wrap it inside the `{}`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   {./rowSums(.)}
```